# Ajax check for file

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, exists

I'm trying to build a table with three columns.

```
Burmese   /   English   /  exists
some word /  some def   / yes
next      /  next      /  yes
last      /   last      / no
third     /  third     /  no
fourth    /  fourth    /  yes
etc.      /   etc.     /  etc
```

Basically I was the loop to send a get request for the file, and if it exists (success) set var exists to "Does Exist", and if it doesn't exist, set var exists to "Does not Exist".

```
somefunction() {
var mySecondArray = "an array that I've created and works fine";
n = mySecondArray.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     var exists = "Exists";
     var something = $.get("/static/audio/ChinState/"+mySecondArray[i].key+".ogg")
                    .done(function() {
                        exists = "Does not Exist";
                        return exists;
                     }).fail(function() {
                         exists = "Does Exist";
                        return exists;
                     });
                       $("table#vocabTable").append("<tr><td>"+mySecondArray[i].key+"</td><td>"+mySecondArray[i].value+"</td><td>"+exists+"</td></tr>");    
 }
}
```

It appears that the table is getting created before the call finishes, so then I tried this.

```
  somefunction() {
  var mySecondArray = "an array that I've created and works fine";
  n = mySecondArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var exists = "Exists";
        var something = $.get("/static/audio/ChinState/"+mySecondArray[i].key+".ogg")
                    .done(function() {
                        exists = "Does not Exist";
                       $("table#vocabTable").append("<tr><td>"+mySecondArray[i].key+"</td><td>"+mySecondArray[i].value+"</td><td>"+exists+"</td></tr>");
                     }).fail(function() {
                         exists = "Does Exist";
                       $("table#vocabTable").append("<tr><td>"+mySecondArray[i].key+"</td><td>"+mySecondArray[i].value+"</td><td>"+exists+"</td></tr>");
                     });
    }
 }
```

but then it says `mySecondArray[i]` is undefined.  So I tried passing in `mySecondArray` and `i` to the function, but same result.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Where are you defining `mySecondArray`? It's not in scope.

Comment: I define it in the function that contains the for loop.  I'm not so good with var scope, so I'm not sure how to pass it into .done, and .fail.

Comment: Ok, what about `n`? Can it ever be greater than the length of your array?

Comment: no, n is also already defined.  I didn't include either of those because they work fine on their own.  It's only in the context of the ajax call that the array doesn't populate with the desired data.